# Symfony 4.4 Auth0 how to completely logout user from the application

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, oauth, auth0

### Basic info:

I created a test application to test if SSO (Single sign on) works. I use Auth0 as a SSO provider. Symfony 4.4 as application framework. I used [this](https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-symfony-app-and-adding-authentication/#Aside--Using-Auth0-with-Symfony) article from Auth0 to create the basics. So far I can login/logout.

### Problem:

When I login once (with credentials), logout after and then login again I am instandly logged in with the same account I used before. Without needing to fill in credentials again. It seems to remember the session or somehow does not completely logout a user. I want the user to have to login again with credentials after it logged out. Since some of my users will use one computer for the applications (so switching user is needed).

### Possible fix/Extra info:

According to there docs/community I should look at [this](https://auth0.com/docs/logout). But this seems to mean that I need API calls to add the `?federated`. Which the setup example does not use (probably the library does it for me). Also my logout function in the SecurityController that is generated by the `make:auth` (or `make:user`) doesn't execute the code anymore. Even if I change the function name it still logged me out. Only untill I remove/change the route name it stops. It's probably very bad but maybe if I had the chance to execute a API call when I logout I could do this API call.

The best thing I could imagine to do is change some settings in symfony or add some small piece of code to make it logout correclty. But I dont know how.

### My code:

**SecurityController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        // Does not trigger at all. It does not stop the page but just continues to redirect and logout.
        dump($this->get('session'));
        dump($session);
        dump("test");
        exit();
        throw new \Exception('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall');
    }
}
```

**Auth0ResourceOwner.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner\GenericOAuth2ResourceOwner;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class Auth0ResourceOwner extends GenericOAuth2ResourceOwner
{
    protected $paths = array(
        'identifier' => 'user_id',
        'nickname' => 'nickname',
        'realname' => 'name',
        'email' => 'email',
        'profilepicture' => 'picture',
    );

    public function getAuthorizationUrl($redirectUri, array $extraParameters = array())
    {
        return parent::getAuthorizationUrl($redirectUri, array_merge(array(
            'audience' => $this->options['audience'],
        ), $extraParameters));
    }

    protected function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'authorization_url' => '{base_url}/authorize',
            'access_token_url' => '{base_url}/oauth/token',
            'infos_url' => '{base_url}/userinfo',
            'audience' => '{base_url}/userinfo',
        ));

        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'base_url',
        ));

        $normalizer = function (Options $options, $value) {
            return str_replace('{base_url}', $options['base_url'], $value);
        };

        $resolver->setNormalizer('authorization_url', $normalizer);
        $resolver->setNormalizer('access_token_url', $normalizer);
        $resolver->setNormalizer('infos_url', $normalizer);
        $resolver->setNormalizer('audience', $normalizer);
    }
}
```

**routes.yaml**

```
hwi_oauth_redirect:
  resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
  prefix: /connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
  resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
  prefix: /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
  resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
  prefix: /login

auth0_login:
  path: /auth0/callback

auth0_logout:
  path: /auth0/logout
  # controller: App/Controller/SecurityController::logout
```

**hwi_oauth.yaml**

```yaml
hwi_oauth:
  firewall_names: [main]
  # https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-configuring_resource_owners.md
  resource_owners:
    auth0:
      type: oauth2
      class: 'App\Auth0ResourceOwner'
      client_id: "%env(AUTH0_CLIENT_ID)%"
      client_secret: "%env(AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET)%"
      base_url: "https://%env(AUTH0_DOMAIN)%"
      scope: "openid profile email"
```

**security.yaml**

```yaml
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Users:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Users
                property: username
        oauth_hwi:
            id: hwi_oauth.user.provider
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: oauth_hwi
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    auth0: "/auth0/callback"
                login_path: /login
                failure_path: /login
                default_target_path: /testPage
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: hwi_oauth.user.provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: /logout
                # target: /login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Everyone that logged in can go to /
        - { path: '^/testPage', roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY] }
```

**.env**

```
AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=not-so-secret-but-secret
AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET=secret
AUTH0_DOMAIN=dev-...
```

**Dump of user:**

```php
TestPageController.php on line 17:
HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUser {#3742 ▼
  #username: "testUser"
}
```

I hope it's understandable. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you have to logout from the oauth service you are using, here is a [similar issue](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/1452).

### Worked out in code:

src/Security/CustomLogoutSuccessHandler.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface;

class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    private $target;

    public function __construct(string $target)
    {
        $this->target = $target;
    }

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->target);
    }
}
```

security.yaml

```yaml
logout:
   path: /logout
   success_handler: App\Security\CustomLogoutSuccessHandler
```

services.yaml

```yaml
services:
   App\Security\CustomLogoutSuccessHandler:
       arguments: ['%env(resolve:LOGOUT_TARGET_URL)%']
```

.env

```
LOGOUT_TARGET_URL=https://{yourAuth0AppDomain}.auth0.com/v2/logout?returnTo={yourRedirectURL}&client_id={secret}
```

Using code from the Github issue redirects you 4 times. Logout->Route->(.env)Auth0->Route.

Using code shown above redirects you 3 times. Logout->Auth0->Route. Just a small improvement.

[Code from this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64703630/11592836)

Comment: Oof... my mistake! I will add the security.yaml to my question. I do have the logout registered btw.

Comment: Thanks for adding it, can you try to replace `/logout` by `app_logout`, which refers to the logout function of your controller (don't forget to remove the dumps and exit before trying)

Comment: Hmm, strange. I manually changed those things to /logout and the dumps just to try. But now I do what you say and thus move them back. Now I seem to get the error/throw exception code inside the logout function. With ofcourse the message being: `This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.` Im still logged in now. It didn't do this before and I dont know what is now different then before :P. So what to do now? It seems my logout is not intercepted by the firewall anymore.

Comment: Can you remove the `throw` function ? 
As specified in the docs : By sending a user to the app_logout route (i.e. to /logout) Symfony will un-authenticate the current user and redirect them.
[https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/security.html#logging-out](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/security.html#logging-out)

Comment: It asks me to return an object: `The controller must return a "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response" object but it returned null. Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?` Even with the :void after the function.

Comment: Do you think its a problem with the security.yaml? Because when I use `/logout` as `path` I do get logged out (application side). But I think just not logged out from Auth0. Could it be possible Oauth/Auth0 bundles don't see the logout correctly? And thereby do not logout correctly?

Comment: Hmm it looks like that you have to logout from the oauth service you are using, here is a [similar issue](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/1452)

Comment: Hey @gdus, your link fixed my issue! Thank you very much. It still seems a bit double with the logout process but at least it works. Maybe you can change your answer to the one in the issue. Then I will accept the answer and maybe edit it a bit to make it more clear. Since the github answer was understandable but not well documented.

Comment: Glad to have helped you, this oauth case is interesting and could help someone in the future

Comment: I hope ur good with my edit. Think it will be more clear and it also improves loading time.